# Terrain hugging line in Google Earth?

Tags: 3d, kml, geospatial, google-earth

Is it possible to generate a terrain-hugging line in the 3D view of Google Earth? Normal lines simply overlay the map and do not hug the terrain in the 3D view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up altitudeMode in the kml reference. You want "clamp to ground".